# How to identify the WhatsApp sender of a media while playing it from the gallery?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video, images, gallery, media-files

When media are received through WhatsApp groups and contacts, they are stored in the storage and are available for the media scanner to list them. When I view the `WhatsApp videos` folder in MXPlayer, I see the videos that I received through WhatsApp.

Occasionally, when I see such an interesting video or image, I forward it to some people or groups, but later to realize that I received it through them. This strikes only when I open the chat history to see the same media sent by someone else.

**Question:**
In this situation, I want to find out the sender (or the group) without opening and scanning the WhatsApp messages to avoid this embarrassment.   I guess the file naming convention only helps to find the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the media's metadata. If the sender's name is there, you can identify it that way.

Otherwise, you can ask WhatsApp developers to add the sender's name to the title or something.

Or if you want, you can manually sort the files.

It's all up to the app.

Comment: How do you look the metadata? I tried to view the properties of a media in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/` and could not figure out who sent it.

Comment: @Narayanan Go to a picture in gallery -> Open menu -> Click Details -> Profit

Comment: Metadata contains no info about the sender.

Answer (score 1):

I am a member of "many" groups of which friends added me there.

So, I had one idea on how to know without checking all the messages and going to Chat Rooms, etc.
Just click on `Group Icon`, select the `Info` icon now, and there you will find `Media`.
Within media, now you have the `Name of sender`.
You can actually check all the media without them knowing that you read the messages.

I don't think it's the exact answer to your question, but it's called '*Workaround*'.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the Video/Image in the gallery, sort to view it by dates, and open the details, it will show 20170622 which is the YYYYMMDD.

If you hadn't deleted the WhatsApp Chat, it would be easy to figure out from Media's Metadata, just a suggestion.