# Gallery: how to see Whatsapp image in chat?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gallery

In my Gallery  I see an image; by its name I guess it is from WhatsApp.  How do I know from which chat it was? I would not like to spend my day opening each and every  chat for years and scrolling, praying to stumble upon that particular image.  I think in the case of an image originated  from  Skype, there is a menu item in Gallery  like "See image in chat",  which  opens the chat in question in one click, but not for WhatsApp?

Comment: That sounds like a feature specific to Skype that may not exist within WhatsApp. This feature could also be dependent on your phone/device's make/model/Android version, all of which would be helpful information for those looking for a solution!

Comment: I checked on my Samsung Galaxy M12, Android 13 using the Samsung Gallery app and Google Photos app. As far as I can see, there's no such menu found in the apps for Skype images.

Comment: Related: [How to identify the WhatsApp sender of a media while playing it from the gallery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129821/44325) (not directly answering the question because AFAIK, WhatsApp images don't contain any metadata related to chat)